# Twilio msg status is always remains Sent

Tags: java, api, scala, sms, twilio

Messages are not delivered to numbers but Twilio is charging me and giving me status `sent` only with my code.

```
private val client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
def sendSMS(smsTo: String) = {
   val params = Map("To" -> smsTo, "From" -> twilioNumber, "Body" -> "status?")
   val messageFactory = client.getAccount.getSmsFactory
   messageFactory.create(params)
}
```

But when I am using  API Explorer its giving status `delivered`.

Is it my code's fault or Twilio?

I want my SMS delivered to users.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here here.

When you send the SMS message using the REST API (the Java/Scala helper library here) you are getting the status `sent` because Twilio has sent the message to the carrier. The carrier will typically update Twilio to say the message was delivered.

There should be nothing wrong with your code at all. What you can do is capture the return value from:

```
messageFactory.create(params)
```

Which will contain a message ID (`messageSID` below). You can then fetch this message from the server to get an update on its status with something like:

```
var params = Map("SID" -> messageSID)
client.getAccount.getSmsMessage(params)
```

The full list of [status are here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#sms-status-values). But it looks like everything you have should be spot on. Hope this helps.

Comment: what i do with response? when i know it always return `sent`

Comment: You can use the Message ID to get an updated status. As progression from `sent` to `delivered` can take a few seconds. So you may well find that calling create() always get you the status `sent`, but if you get the message status with the REST API a little later, you'll get `delivered`.